# iOS CGAffineTransform with Masking

Tags: ios, swift, masking, cgaffinetransform

Im currently developing an iOS Application where you can process an image. (rotating, zooming, translating). Im using an uiimageview where i added gestures. This works fine but i also have some masking rectangle of a fixed size. [Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue1fw.png)

After i processed my image i want the content which is inside my masking rectangle.
I also want the four edge points of the masking rectangle of the processed image.

I know i have to apply the imageview transform to the points somehow, but its not working.

```
    let points = maskView.edgePoints()

    let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationPoint.x, y: translationPoint.y)
    let rotateTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotationAngle))
    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: xScale, y: yScale)

    let finalTransform = rotateTransform.concatenating(scaleTransform).concatenating(translateTransform)

    let topleftPoint = points[0].applying(finalTransform)
    let toprightPoint = points[1].applying(finalTransform)
    let bottomleftPoint = points[2].applying(finalTransform)
    let bottomrightPoint = points[3].applying(finalTransform)
```

Edge point results: [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx7e2.png)

Topleft: (50.75, -8.75)

Topright: (63.6072332330383, -365.252863911729)

Bottomleft: (-172.064289944831, -16.7857707706489)

Bottomright: (-159.207056711792, -373.288634682378)

But the Topleft should be something like (0,0) 
and the Bottomleft something like (40,200)?

Maybe you can give me some hints or useful links!

Thx in advance!

Comment: You want to crop portion under that black rect ?

Comment: you can set clip to bound true

Comment: I am not able to find out what actually you are trying to do ? And why you are applying transform to   `maskView.edgePoints`  ? you want your black border move accordingly :?

Comment: More information is needed I think. Does `points` contain the `frame` of the view or the `bounds`? If it's frame, there's no reason top left should be 0,0. You will probably also get incoherent results unless the `anchorPoint` of whatever you're applying the transform on matches that of `points`. This is also info that is missing.

Comment: The black rectangle remains steady. The red apple card can be zoomed,scaled and translated. After finishing the image processing, the imageview has a specific transform matrix. I want to know the cropping rectangle of the imageview.
Initial position:(Topleft, Topright, bottomleft, bottomright):  ((0,0), (0,280), (180, 0), (180, 280)). e.g. When i move the imageview 50px down, the edgepoints of the mask should be ((0,50), (0,320), (180,50), (180,320)).
When i only do translation it works. But not combined with scaling and rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your transformation order. Right now your transformation order is Rotate Scale Translate, it should be Scale Rotate Translate instead.

```
let finalTransform = scaleTransform.concatenating(rotateTransform).concatenating(translateTransform)
```